# No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name')

Tags: android, label, android-resources

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.kun.www.love.MainActivity">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/party"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="Happy Birthday, Kun"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:fontFamily="san-serif-light"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Love"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:fontFamily="san-serif-light"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>


<resources>
    <string
        name="Love"
        >From Kun</string>
</resources>
```

This is the error. I tried to solve it, but I failed.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check in the file   **res/values/strings.xml** have app_name or not? if its not add

```
 <string name="app_name">"Your App name"</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add in your manifest file in application tag this below line

```
    android:label="@string/app_name"
```

and also add in string.xml file below line

```
<string name="app_name">App Name</string>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

XML file saved at `res/values/strings.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string
        name="Love"
        >From Kun</string>
</resources>
```

and also have this

```
<string name="app_name">"My App"</string>
```